How to cut a video with FFmpeg with no (or minimal) re-encoding?
We can cut a video with FFmpeg with no re-encoding with:
ffmpeg -ss 120 -t 60 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4

(This question's answer suggests to also use -avoid_negative_ts make_zero but it does not explain why)
Unfortunately, the result is often choppy or non-smooth in the first seconds, as detailed here (closed because off-topic), because the cut point doesn't necessarily coincide with a keyframe.
Some more complex solutions involve reencoding just the beginning until the next keyframe, and then use copy codec for the rest of the video. The question Cut a video in between key frames without re-encoding the full video using FFpmeg? is interesting and gives a beginning of solution, but closed (off-topic).
TL;DR: Is there a modern ready-to-use solution inside FFmpeg that allows to do this cut without having to do all these tasks manually?
Or something like this in a single pass of FFmpeg with no manual re-concatenation?

The choppy starting issue is partially related to the video player. Example (using FFmpeg 5.1.2): Create input video: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=300 -c:v libx264 -g 250 input.mp4, Cut the video: ffmpeg -y -ss 120 -t 60 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4, Play using FFplay: ffplay output.mp4. The played video looks perfect with FFplay, but there are issues with other players. Can you please be more specific, about the versions and the players... Please try to post a reproducible example. (Note that I can't think of any good solution).

@Rotem I had this problem with multiple video players such as Media Player Classic, the latest version if I remember correctly (2.1.4). Even if it works with another player, the problem that the cut point doesn't coincide with keyframe still exists. Do you know a solution for this?

I don't know a solution, but maybe someone does. Before asking for a general solution, I recommend you to start with a reproducible and specific example.

Note: I have already started a bounty on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63548027/cut-a-video-in-between-key-frames-without-re-encoding-the-full-video-using-ffpme, but sadly, this question was closed just after I started the bounty. Let's hope someone has an idea here :)

What's with the start time being after the stop time?  Using -ss 120 -t 60 shouldn't work. I also thought it was -to?

There's a free GUI software which can do exactly what you wish for: Free Video Editor. Maybe it's worth a shot. Unfortunately, with ffmpeg you'll need at least 3 steps, as detailed in my answer

@Basj is ffmpeg absolutely required? Otherwise there is an awesome piece of software called lossless cut that does a remarkable job with any video cut without re-encoding. See https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/blob/master/cli.md

The only no-frills solution is to re-encode everything
The only way to do this with a single ffmpeg call is to re-encode the whole video, by leaving away the -c: copy :
ffmpeg -ss 120 -t 60 -i input.mp4 output.mp4

Here below you can find some reasons for this.
Why what you ask for won't work
Reason A: the concat demuxer needs a .txt file in order to work,
as is clearly stated in the documentation.
There's also a concat protocol, but it won't work on the mp4 container, so this will need re-encoding.
Another way to concatenate files is using filter-complex as this answer shows:
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 20:00 -i inputA.avi -ss 0 -t 10:00 -i inputB.avi -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" out.mp4

But the filter-complex logic is decode>filter>encode, so this won't help.
Reason B: You have to choose between either exact cutting or stream copy
Let's pretend for a moment we already have the right keyframe, and let's
look at your example from this answer you linked:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 5 -to 6.131 trimmed.mp4

Make input.txt for the concat demuxer:
file 'trimmed.mp4' 
file 'input.mp4' 
inpoint 6.131

Concatenate:
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4


So, for the first step you don't want to use copy as you need to make an exact cut. As you can read in the documentation, if -ss is used together with copy, the seeking will be inaccurate, and the cut will be made at the nearest preceding key frame.
At the same time, in the second step using concat, you want to use copy to avoid re-encoding.
The issue is that copy is a codec option which can be set, so it will affect the processing of the whole output. So, even if ffmpeg can process multiple input files which you can even trim in one step (as already linked above), if you want to run ffmpeg in one only line, you'll have to choose between either exact cutting, or stream copying. The two mutually exclude each other.

In order to automate, you'll have to write a script
Given all this, if you want to run a single command without doing the re-encoding, you'll need to write a script, with the tools you prefer.
To simplify this, I'd avoid to search for key frames and do the following steps. Let's assume you want to cut away the first t=5 seconds of your video:

rough-cut the first part from start to t+10 seconds, to make sure you hit a keyframe far away enough from your real cutting point :
ffmpeg -ss 00:00 -to 15 -i input.mp4 -c: copy temp.mp4


fine-cut the beginning of the first part :
ffmpeg -ss 5 -i temp.mp4 -avoid_negative_ts 2 trimmed.mp4


create the input.txt file. The stitching point is at t+10 = 15 seconds :
trimmed.mp4
input.mp4
input 15


concatenate :
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4



It should be fairly easy to write a script which automates these 4 steps.
You may have to refine this, as I get a warning about non-compliant timestamps from the concat demuxer.

If you switch the containers to .mkv and set the timestamp to zero for each file, they will concat without the DTS warnings. ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero output.mkv

I have a script I use to concatenate video.  It doesn't help with cutting out the sections, but it will concatenate any mp4's you throw at it.  I use an alias like this:
alias concatvid='~/Documents/pub/bash/myapps/concat_video.sh'

#!/bin/bash

source_files=("$@")
file_type=""
list_file="tmp.txt"
container_swap=()
output_file="concat_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").mkv"
final_source=()

if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [FILE] [FILE]..."
    echo "Concatenate mpeg-4 video. Requires two files, minimum."
    exit 1
fi

switch_containers() {
    counter=1
    for file in "${source_files[@]}"; do
        base_name="${file%.*}"
        intermediate_file="${base_name}_$counter.mkv"
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$file" -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero "$intermediate_file"
        container_swap+=("$intermediate_file")
        counter=$((counter + 1))
    done
    final_source=("${container_swap[@]}")
}

# Determine media type of input files
for file in "${source_files[@]}"; do
    extension="${file##*.}"
    if [ "$extension" == "mkv" ]; then
        file_type="mkv"
    elif [ "$extension" == "mp4" ]; then
        file_type="mp4"
    else
        echo "Unsupported file type: $extension"
        exit 1
    fi
done

if [ "$file_type" == "mp4" ]; then
    switch_containers
else
    final_source=("${source_files[@]}")
fi

# Create tmp.txt for concatenation
> "$list_file"
for file in "${final_source[@]}"; do
    echo "file '$file'" >> "$list_file"
done

# Concatenate files
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f concat -safe 0 -i "$list_file" -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -movflags +faststart "$output_file" && rm "$list_file"

if [ "${#container_swap[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    rm "${container_swap[@]}"
fi

exit 0

Save as: concat_video.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x concat_video.sh
Usage: ./concat_video.sh video1.mp4 video2.mp4 ...and so on.
If you set the alias, you can use it from any directory.
concatvid video1.mp4 video2.mp4 ...


Cutting at the nearest key frame, re-encoding the relevant part before the key frame and concatenating is apparently quite challenging...
Note: The following solutions are not very practical - treat them as a "proof of concept".
It looks like concat demuxer has a bug, and it doesn't set the timestamps perfectly (at the "stitching point").
It also looks like video players are sensitive to the P/B frames structure of the concatenated parts. (With high framerate, we can't notice, but with 1fps framerate, there are noticeable glitches).

The "naïve solution":
ffmpeg -y -ss 120 -to 180 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
As demonstrated in my comment, it's working when played with FFplay, but not working with most players.
Executing ffprobe -show_entries packet=flags output.mp4, shows that the first packets are marked with flags=_D.
flags=_D marks the packets (encoded frames) as discarded. (should be dropped after decoding).
MP4 file container supports "discarded packets", but most video players ignore the flag, making the "naïve solution" impractical.

Cutting at the key frame, re-encoding only the first part, and concatenating:
We may try the following stages:

Find the last keyframe before the cutting point.
Create the second video part without re-encoding - start cutting from the key frame and finish at the desired end time.
Create the first video part with re-encoding - start at the desired start time, and end one frame before the key frame.
Concatenate the two video files without re-encoding.


For demonstrating the process, we are going to use the following generated video file:
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=300 -c:v libx264 -g 51 input.mp4
We are going to cut the video from second 120 to 180.

Find the last keyframe before the cutting point using FFprobe:
ffprobe -v error -skip_frame nokey -select_streams v:0 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries frame=pts_time -read_intervals "120%200" input.mp4
pts_time=102.000000
pts_time=153.000000

The nearest keyframe after 120.0 is at 153.0.

Create the second video part without re-encoding:
ffmpeg -y -ss 153 -to 180 -i input.mp4 -c:v copy second_part.ts
We are using MPEG-TS file format, in order to later use concat protocol (concat demuxer is not working properly, and concat protocol doesn't support MP4).

Create the first video part with re-encoding:
ffmpeg -y -ss 120 -to 152.0001 -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -bf 3 -g 32 first_part.ts

Start from the first cutting timestamp, and end one frame before the relevant key frame (add 0.0001 for including the last frame).
Use libx264 codec, for matching the H.264 codec of the second part (the video codec must be the same codec as the input file).
Set the number of B-Frames to 3 (using -bf 3), because the input has 3 consecutive B-Frames (strangely... video playas seems to be sensitive to the B/P frame structure along the video).
Set the GOP size to 32 (using -g 32) - the first and last frames of first_part.ts are going to be a key frames (for preventing a B-Frame at the end of the first part).
Note that we know there are 32 frames from 120.0 to 152.0, because we know that the frame rate is 1fps.


Concatenate the two video files without re-encoding:
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:first_part.ts|second_part.ts" -c copy output.mp4
We are using Concat Protocol - it looks like it's working better than concat demuxer in our case.

Trying to automate the process using a Python script:
Notes:

The Python script is just an example - there are too many cases that are not going to work (it is also doesn't meant to be efficient).
The script was only testes with the specific sample input file (H.264 video without audio...).
In case someone doesn't know Python, I suggest to read the comments.

import subprocess as sp
import shlex
import json

input_file_name = 'input.mp4'  # Input file name
start_pts = 120  # Begin cutting time (in seconds)
end_pts = 180  # End cutting time (in seconds)

output_file_name = 'output.mp4'  # Output file name

# We may build synthetic video for testing: sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=300 -c:v libx264 -g 51 {input_file_name}'))

# Find the last key frame before the cutting point. Consider using -read_intervals {start_pts-10}%{start_pts+1} (for the example are probing the entire input file).
# Example for timestaps of key frames
# 0.0
# 51.0
# 102.0
# 153.0 <-- We are looking for the first key frame after the cutting point.
# 204.0
# ...
data = sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffprobe -v error -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pts_time -select_streams v:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -print_format json {input_file_name}'), stdout=sp.PIPE).stdout
dict = json.loads(data)  # Convert data from JSON string to dictionary
key_pts = 0
for fr in dict['frames']:
    key_pts = float(fr['pts_time'])
    if float(fr['pts_time']) > start_pts:
        break  # Stop searching when the timestamp is grater than start_pts     

# Count the number of frames from start_pts to key_pts (there are 32 frame in out example).
# 120.0
# 121.0
# ...
# 161.0
dict = json.loads(sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pts_time -select_streams v:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -print_format json -read_intervals "{start_pts}%{key_pts+10}" {input_file_name}'), stdout=sp.PIPE).stdout)
# We have to check if pts is in the correct range, because read_intervals is not accurate.
n_prefix_frames = 0  # Number of frames from start_pts to key_pts
pts_before_key = 0  # We are also looking for one timestamp before the key_pts (152.0 in out example)
for fr in dict['frames']:
    pts = float(fr['pts_time'])
    n_prefix_frames += (pts >= start_pts) and (pts < key_pts)  # Going to be 33 in out example
    if pts < key_pts:
        pts_before_key = pts  # Going to be 152.0 in out example

gop_size = n_prefix_frames - 1  # Set the GOP size of the first part to number of frames minus 1 (we want the first and the last frame to be a key frame). We need it for avoiding B-Frame at the end of the first part.

# Get video stream properties
dict = json.loads(sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffprobe -v error -show_streams -select_streams v:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -print_format json {input_file_name}'), stdout=sp.PIPE).stdout)
codec_name = dict['streams'][0]['codec_name']  # Get the codec name
has_b_frames = int(dict['streams'][0]['has_b_frames'])  # Valid values: 0, 1, 2
#pix_fmt = dict['streams'][0]['pix_fmt']  # Pixel format is not required for the specific example.

# Select encoder according to the codec name
if codec_name == 'h264':
    video_encoder = 'libx264'
elif codec_name == 'hevc':
    video_encoder = 'libx265' # HEVC (H.265) was not tested.
else:
    raise Exception('Video codec is not supported')

# There is an issue: when has_b_frames=2, there are 2 or above B-Frames, and we want to know the exact number.
if has_b_frames > 1:
    # Get the picture type of the first 15 frames, for example: I, B, B, B, P, B, B, B, P, B, B, B, P...
    dict = json.loads(sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pict_type -select_streams v:0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -print_format json -read_intervals "%+#15" {input_file_name}'), stdout=sp.PIPE).stdout)

    # Find the maximum number of consecutive B frames
    max_consecutive_b_frames = 0
    consecutive_b_frames_counter = 0
    for frame in dict['frames']:
        if frame['pict_type'] == 'B':
            consecutive_b_frames_counter += 1  # Increase the counter if a B-Frame.
        else:
            consecutive_b_frames_counter = 0  # Reset the counter if not a B-Frame.
        max_consecutive_b_frames = max(max_consecutive_b_frames, consecutive_b_frames_counter)  # May update the maximum

    n_b_frames = max_consecutive_b_frames  # 3 in our example
else:
    n_b_frames = has_b_frames

# Create video file first_part.ts
# Start from start_pts, and end one frame before the relevant key frame (add 0.0001 for including the last frame).
# Use the selected video encoder (libx264 or libx265...) - the video codec must be the same codec as of the input file.
# Set the number of B-Frames to n_b_frames
# Set the GOP size to n_prefix_frames - 1 (the first and last frame of first_part.ts is going to be a key frame).
# Use MPEG-TS output file format for supporting concat protocol.
sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -ss {start_pts} -to {pts_before_key+0.0001} -i {input_file_name} -c:v {video_encoder} -bf {n_b_frames} -g {gop_size} first_part.ts'))

# Create video file second_part.ts from key_pts to end_pts, without re-encoding
sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -ss {key_pts} -to {end_pts} -i {input_file_name} -c:v copy second_part.ts'))

# Use concat protocol for concatenating the first and the second video parts
# It seems like concat protocol is more reliable than concat demuxer, when it comes to setting the time stamps correctly.
# Note: the is a warning message "Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 3006000)", but the output file seems to be perfect.
sp.run(shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -y -i concat:first_part.ts|second_part.ts -c copy {output_file_name}'))

